# Differential equation....

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let y(x) be the continuous solution of the initial value problem, 
$$\frac{dy} {dx}  + 2y=f(x)$$, 
$y(0)=0$
where 
$$f(x) =\begin{cases} 1&\text{if  }x\in[0,1]\\0&\text{if  }x>1\end{cases}$$
 then find $$y(\frac{3}{2})$$

This question has been asked in net csir 2015..... And I am not able to solve it.... Please guide me.... in solving the integral we arrive at after taking integrating factor which is $e^{2x} $ and then we get the solution as
$$e^{2x}. y=\int f(x). e^{2x} dx + c$$
where c is arbitrary constant.... 
Please help me to solve this further....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to have gotten to this point on your own
$$
\frac{d}{dx}[e^{2x}y(x)] = f(x)e^{2x}
$$
You know $y(0)$ and you want $y(3/2)$. So simply integrate the equation over this interval
$$
\int_0^{3/2}\frac{d}{dx}[e^{2x}y(x)]dx = e^{3}y(3/2) - y(0) = \int_0^{3/2} f(x)e^{2x}dx = \int_0^{1}e^{2x}dx = \frac{e^2-1}{2}
$$
Solving this and using $y(0) = 0$ gives
$$
y(3/2) = \frac{e^2 - 1}{2e^3}
$$

Comment: Tell me one thing.... When we Integrate over 0 to 3/2 shall we not add arbitrary constant.....??

Comment: You could, but it would make it into $[e^3y(3/2) + C] - [y(0) + C]$, and the $C$ cancels out.

Comment: Okay.... Thanks....

Comment: Sorry sorry.... U got me wrong.... I meant to add constant while integrating from 0 to 3/2.....not before...... That was reduced to zero while differentiating.....

Comment: The constant of integration is used in indefinite integration because the antiderivative of a function is only defined up to a constant. For a definite integral, the value of the integral is equal to the difference in the value of the antiderivative at the endpoints of the interval. This difference will cancel out the constant of integration, as it is the same at both points.

Comment: Okays i got it... Thank you once again......